# Error running script.php: Port 9000 is busy

Tags: php, linux, port, xdebug, phpstorm

I set `php.ini` and `Debug config` in `phpstorm`. Trying to debug php script outputs in phpstorm Event log with:

```
"Error running script.php: Port 9000 is busy"
```

end of php.ini:

```
        [XDebug]
        zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
        xdebug.remote_enable=1
        xdebug.remote_port="9000" (the default port is 9000)
        xdebug.profiler_enable=1
        xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
        xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/etc/php5/xdebug/profiler_output_dir"
```

Debug port in pStorm is also set on 9000.  `netstat -na` outputs with:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

What if I set to other port. eg setting it to `10001` seems to do the job. Or just how to make it work properly. I am not sure if I understand how the `xDebug` works. Its like running `Debug("script.php")(Shift+F9)` in phpstorm with set breakpoint in file ?

Does somebody have an idea ?

**EDIT:**

From:
http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

```
xdebug.remote_port
Type: integer, Default value: 9000
The port to which Xdebug tries to connect on the remote host. Port 9000 is the default for both the client and the bundled debugclient. As many clients use this port number, it is best to leave this setting unchanged.
```

What if I change port for other than 9000 ? Maybe something over 50k .

Comment: *"Port 9000 is busy"* -- this means that another app (not PhpStorm .. or completely different PhpStorm instance) is already listens on that port. IDE listens (receives connections) on that port and xdebug is the one who connects to IDE and not other way around. Official xdebug documentation has detailed explanation of how xdebug works with debug client (IDE): http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could not identify with lsof and netstat the pid of process running on **9000** port. Temporary simplest sollution is just to change the port in `phpstorm` and `php.ini` for something else not actually used (like **10k**).

Answer (score 16):

The process, which is running on port 9000, could be PhpStorm itself.

Check the currently used ports like Jacob mentioned (on Windows cmd: `netstat -a -b`):
[image]

If **PhpStorm.exe** ist listed under **:9000** you just have to change the port of **built-in server** in settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > **Debugger** to e.g. *63342* (this was the default setting of my teammates PhpStorm installation).

Comment: For OSX, you can find the app bound to port 9000 using - lsof -n -i4TCP:9000 | grep LISTEN

Answer (score 8):

GNU/Linux Solution (because there is life beyond Windows) :

Following the solution of @aqm

first find process using port 9000.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :9000
```

You will get an output like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3993/programname
```

You need PID to kill process with this command:

```
kill -9 3993
```

---

***NOTE***: Maybe your process not show his PID, is possible that you are running PHP-FPM that uses as default port 9000, in this case you can change PHP-FPM port or PHP Xdebug port.

---

SOLUTION 1 - Changing your Xdebug configuration:

edit `/etc/php/php.ini`

search for `xdebug.remote_port=9000` and replace with your new port

---

SOLUTION 2 - Changing PHP-FPM Port:

Edit `/etc/php/php-fpm.conf`

Search line with `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and replace 9000 with your new port

then reload service:

```
systemctl reload php-fpm
```

Then edit your nginx or apache config to tell this new port, search for `127.0.0.1:9000` in `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and replace it with your new port

reload your server:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

or

```
systemctl reload httpd
```

---

I hope it helps :),

namaste.

Answer (score 5):

Basically some other process is using 9000 and not using letting it go, normally for me another IDE running at the same time

Windows fix ->

1. FIND PROCESS USING 9000

open up cmd.exe

netstat -o

```
C:\Users\AMC75>netstat -o

Active Connections

 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    10.6.176.132:27018     livlt0124661:55375     ESTABLISHED     11104
 TCP    10.6.176.132:49271     chilynfe01:5061        ESTABLISHED     10120
 TCP    10.6.176.132:49379     hhefs14:netbios-ssn    ESTABLISHED     4
 TCP    10.6.176.132:49383     chifs08:netbios-ssn    ESTABLISHED     4
 TCP    10.6.176.132:51034     157.55.56.143:40002    ESTABLISHED     11104
 TCP    10.6.176.132:51038     db3msgr6011007:https   ESTABLISHED     11104
 TCP    10.6.176.132:51049     wb-in-f125:5222        ESTABLISHED     10860
 TCP    10.6.176.132:51282     wpapp020:50124         ESTABLISHED     848
 TCP    10.6.176.132:53014     ec2-107-23-104-135:https  ESTABLISHED     10860
 TCP    10.6.176.132:53015     ec2-107-23-104-135:https  ESTABLISHED     10860
 TCP    10.6.176.132:54774     157.56.116.205:12350   ESTABLISHED     11104
 TCP    10.6.176.132:54822     a23-198-48-60:https    CLOSE_WAIT      7500
 TCP    10.6.176.132:55166     upmon070:3306          ESTABLISHED     2652
 TCP    10.6.176.132:55261     lhr08s03-in-f9:http    ESTABLISHED     10860
 TCP    10.6.176.132:55570     upmon070:3306          ESTABLISHED     10980
..... BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

1. KILL PROCESS

taskkill /PID XXXX

1. PROFIT ... ?, well you should now be able to run the debugger

Answer (score 5):

note to future self:

In my case this was caused by using the virtual machine port forwarding (vagrant on Virtual Box). I thought forwarding `9000` was a good idea.

SOLUTION: connect to VM IP `10.166.53.1` which is the standard Virtual Box
[image]

contents of my `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/xdebug.ini`

```
; xdebug configuration
; xdebug.remote_host = localhost
zend_extension =  /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log
```

Comment: Same problem here. Apparently you don't need to forward this port. Removing the forwarding of port 9000 fixed it for me. Now I can use Vagrant + XDebug + PhpStorm

Answer (score 2):

First, even if is a little off topic, I think it helps. I am using a different network interface for each docker-composer project. This way I can map a persistent domain name in /etc/hosts without any worries, in this example is `192.168.33.102 project.domain.local`.

Here is an example of yaml setup:

```
nginx:
  build: docker-images/nginx
  links:
    - "php"
  ports:
    - "192.168.33.102:80:80"
php:
  build: docker-images/php/7.0.1-fpm
  ports:
    - "192.168.33.102:10000:9000"
```

The php container listen on *9001* for `php7.0-fpm` and on *9000* for `xdebug` and does not expose any ports.

PhpStorm Debug Port is set to default 9000 and the server host is set to `192.168.33.102` (or the value from /etc/hosts, which is `project.domain.local`).

As can be seen in the ports of php container, a different mapping port is set to 10000, it can be any other different value than 9000, to remove the busy error from PhpStorm.

Also, it is important to bind the port on docker-compose. It did not worked without mapping the port and it did not work with *9000:9000*.

Hope it helps someone else!

PS: here is the xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works:

on linux view used ports with

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :90
```

results

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       22719/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    OUÇA       22726/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::9003                 :::*                    OUÇA       5252/java
```

then i changed

on dockerfile:

```
&& echo "xdebug.client_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
```

and on phpstorm settings

Settings > PHP > Debug:

Xdebug section: Debug port 9001

Comment: NB `client_port` is the  xdebug3 replacement for `remote_port` - a few other variables changed as well, like the default port being `9003` instead of `9000`, see https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide